# How do I pass an asp variable to a selectcommand?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to pass a variable "PIN2" that I am retrieving like below to a  SelectCommand statement in a asp SqlDataSource tag

> <%
>
> ```
> Dim PIN As String = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
> Dim PIN2 As String = Right(PIN, 6)
>  %>
> ```

Thanks

Comment: And the problem you are having with this is?

Comment: @Oded it looks like he is trying to do `SelectCommand="SELECT ... <% Dim PIN ... %>" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about refactoring your PIN to your code-behind in a Session Variable and then using it inside your SQLDataSource tag as a SessionParameter.

Like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server" language="vb" >

    Partial Class MyPending
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            Dim PIN As String = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
            Dim PIN2 As String = Right(PIN, 6)
            Session("PIN") = PIN2   
        End Sub            

    End Class
</script>
```

.

```
<asp:sqldatasource id="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" selectcommand="... WHERE USERPIN=@thepin">
  <selectparameters>
    <asp:sessionparameter sessionfield="PIN" type="String" name="thepin" />
  </selectparameters>
</asp:sqldatasource>
```

Comment: My VB isn't the greatest.  I am getting an error saying that a declaration is expected for the line "session("PIN") = PIN2

Comment: Make sure it is `Session("PIN")` , the capital `S` is important.

Comment: This is my code behind code.

Partial Class MyPending
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim PIN As String = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
    Dim PIN2 As String = Right(PIN, 6)
    Session("PIN") = PIN2

End Class

This is the error I get.  
Line 5:      Dim PIN As String = Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")
Line 6:      Dim PIN2 As String = Right(PIN, 6)
Line 7:      Session("PIN") = PIN2
Line 8:  
Line 9:  End Class

Comment: You should put your code inside the `Page_Load` method. : ) I updated my answer to include more of the code - does it work now?

Comment: Great! Don't forget to click the checkmark next to the post to say "This one was the answer". And, welcome to StackOverflow! Ask moar questions, om-nom-nom.